# Why Shanideva is at Lord Hanuman's feet in statue? Why Lord Hanuman is worshipped to decrease effects of Shani deva?

Tags: ramayana, hanuman

I have seen Lord Hanuman Temple statue many times. who is there in the feet of Lord Hanuman? Is he shani deva? If so why is he there in his feet? Also Lord Hanuman is worshipped to decrease effects of Shani deva? What is the story behind it?

Comment: These stories do not have any authenticity or valid sources. For example, most of the popular Vrat stories are purely local and not more than two centuries old. Purans too have lots of stories regarding different Vrats but hardly anyone follows them. Its funny!
Ganesha's cursing Moon story exists in none of the Purans but its one of the most popular stories copy/pasted in hundreds of blogs. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Sani told Hanuman that I will catch you. Hanuman said I am in rama karya. You should come afterwards. But sani was adamant. He said I have to catch you. Hanuman thinked for a while and said ok. Sani sat on hanuman's shoulder. Hanuman flied in the sky with great speed and sani could not bear the speed. He pleaded to stop, or we will go down. Hanuman obliged. Sani was tired. He regained energy and said I will catch your legs. Hanuman said ok. Sani caught his leg and hanuman ran into the forest. Sani was wounded as he was thrashed by boulders and thorns. He pleaded to stop. Hanuman stopped. Sani with folded hands told Hanuman I will not catch you and whoever worships you, will not catch them also.

**Source**

**Kothayin paadhai**  by **Mukkur Lakshmi narasimhachar  3rd volume.**

A **shloka** start with a line

> Namah Krishnaya  neelaya sidhi kanda nibaya cha